# Convert Stream Dataframe into Spark Dataframe using scala and spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following stream dataframe.

```
+----------------------------------
|______value______________________| 
| I am going to school         |   
| why are you crying         | 
| You are not very good my friend |
```

I have created the above dataframe using below code

```
val readStream = existingSparkSession
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostAddress)
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .option("subscribe", "myTopic.raw")
      .load()
```

I want to store the same stream dataframe into spark dataframe. is that possible to convert so in scala and spark? because at the end I want to convert the spark dataframe into a list of sentences. Issue with stream dataframe is i am unable to convert it directly into a list that I can iterate and do some data processing actions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do many of standard operations on the stream that you're getting from Kafka, but you need to take into account the differences in semantics between batch and streaming processing - refer to the [Spark docs for that](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).

Also, when you're getting data from Kafka, the set of columns is [fixed](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries), and you get a binary payload that you need to cast the `value` column to string, or something like this (see docs):

```scala
val df = readStream.select($"value".cast("string").alias("sentences"))
```

after that you'll get a dataframe with actual payload, and start processing.  Depending on the complexity of processing, you may need to revert to the [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) functionality, but that may not be necessary - you need to provide more details on what kind of processing you need to do.

Comment: I want to convert rows of one column of a stream dataframe into a list so that I can iterate through the list to calculated a weighted average @Alex

Comment: In most cases you can implement it using the Spark API, by using window functions, etc. In the worst case, you have the foreachBatch option